# Rails password_reset recordnotfound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, forgot-password

I am getting an error when I pass in my url to reset my password for example: localhost:3000/password_reset/SADASIJDSIDJ1231231/edit <---- gives me ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound and its pointing at in my password_reset_controller

```
def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  end
```

This is my application controller (notice the "include SessionsHelper")

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  #om du lägger till kod här kmr inte sessions funka när du är inloggad wtf???
  #tog bort detta protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
  protect_from_forgery 

   private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

end
```

This is my password_reset_controller

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

 def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email sent with password reset instructions."
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
    if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password reset has expired."
    elsif @user.update_attributes(params.permit![:user])
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset!"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

HOW I SOLVED IT:

So thanks to jorge I knew password_reset_token wasn't generated in the database. So I went back to my model/user.rb

```
def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end
```

I added back "save!" it was "save" before. Then I got another error saying password can't be blank.

So I deleted these two lines

```
 # validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, presence: true
  #validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

Instead I added this line

```
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
```

Now everything works. Thanks for your patience jorge. I owe u one big.

Comment: paste your routes.rb related lines

Comment: paste the params[:id] before the find_by.

Comment: Do you have the password_reset_token field in the database?

Comment: like this? "@user = User.(params[:id])find_by_password_reset_token!
" this gave me another error

Comment: yes i have class AddPasswordResetToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_reset_token, :string
    add_column :users, :password_reset_sent_at, :datetime
  end
end

Comment: before the user find do: "puts params[:id]" and paste the output.

Comment: im not sure i follow you, can you paste the full code as an edit of your previous answer? here is the guide i followed https://github.com/railscasts/274-remember-me-reset-password/tree/master/auth-after

Comment: I edited my code, you mean like that?

Comment: I've edited the anwser according to the code you followed.

Comment: Relevant code here is:
resets_password_controller, and routes.
And to problem might be in the route you are using. do a rake_routes to see which is the correct route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check in the database that the a user exists with password reset token "SADASIJDSIDJ1231231"?

Looks like following line is not finding a user:

```
@user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
```

Please include your `User` class - the `send_password_reset` method may not be saving the token correctly.

Comment: Your guess was right, the token was not in the database.

Comment: OMYFREAKINGGOD thank you jorge for guidance.. I will update my answer for how I solved it...!!!